# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter - filtering data depending on EditText value

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm making something like social network using Firebase and I have a problem I cant handle myself. I want to dynamic filter data using FireBaseRecycler View. I`m having something like this:

[image: App screen]

So, I want to getText from EditText and list by names. I tried something like this:

```
final Query queryRef = mUsersDatabase.orderByChild("name");
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersActivity.UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersActivity.UsersViewHolder>(

        Users.class,
        R.layout.users_single_layout,
        UsersActivity.UsersViewHolder.class,
        mUsersDatabase.orderByChild("Users").equalTo(string)

)
```

And passing string from EditText

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            string = editText.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

But what with:

```
mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
container.addView(view);
return view;
```

When I put two first lanes (setAdapter and addView) application crashes and at all I have return view all time I edit EditText. What is more it seems to be very dumb and ridicoulous option, but actually I`ve brain lag. Someone knows a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int start, int before, int count) {

                query = query.toString().trim().toLowerCase();

                final ArrayList<DataModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();


                final CharSequence finalQuery = query;
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        // Clear the filter list
                        filteredList.clear();

                        // If there is no search value, then add all original list items to filter list
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(finalQuery)) {

                            filteredList.addAll(cities);

                        } else {
                            // Iterate in the original List and add it to filter list...
                            for (DataModel item : cities) {
                                if (item.getCity_name().toLowerCase().contains(finalQuery.toString().toLowerCase())
                                        ) {
                                    // Adding Matched items
                                    filteredList.add(item);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Set on UI Thread
                        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                // Notify the List that the DataSet has changed...
                                adapter = new SearchCityAdapter(SearchCityClass.this, filteredList);
                                recyclerSearchCity.setAdapter(adapter);

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }).start();


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Actually I handled it by myself, but this solution had made my eyes open. Thanks!